# Duplicate source information from esri.tasks.PrintTask

Tags: arcgis-server, javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, printing

We are trying out the PrintTask in ArcGIS Server 10.1 pre-release.  When an Esri base map is enabled, we are getting source information in two places in the resulting .pdf.  I can confirm that this was not the case with 10.1 beta, and we are using the same .mxd's for the service.  Is there any way to remove one of these source references, or change the placement?  I didn't see a corresponding parameter in the javascript api.

[image: Screenshot of duplicate source info]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it - in the template .mxd there was a hidden element with the Service Layer Credits dynamic text properties :

```
<dyn type="document" property="service layer credits" separator="\n" emptyStr = " "/>
```

For some reason this element didn't show using the Beta release, so we didn't catch it until now.